What is the name of this audio connector?
Hello I was trying to connect my aux in to an audio switch so that I can use both aux and bluetooth.
I found this strange connector and I cant find it's name /matching pair online.
I'm working on an opel corsa d facelift.


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Based on what I can find online, this is an AIT2PB-06-1AK connector. Below is an example image of the connector and its matching partner from AliExpress (not affiliated; it just happened to be where I could find the pair):


Thank you so much
